# Is there a better way to soql B records by A's idList?

Tags: apex, soql

For example, first I will retrive a List of **A** sObject:

```
List<A__c> A = [SELECT Id, Name FROM A__c WHERE ...];
```

Then I will retrieve a List of **B** sObject by **A** List like:

```
List<String> idList = new List<String>();
for(Integer i = 0; i < A.size()) {
    idList.add(A[i].Id);
}
List<B__c> B = [SELECT Id, Name FROM B__c WHERE A__c IN :idList];
```

Is there any better way to achieve this? How to avoid new a idList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a separate collection (Map, List, or Set), just use the list of records directly:

```
List<A__c> A = [SELECT Id, Name FROM A__c WHERE ...];
List<B__c> B = [SELECT Id, Name FROM B__c WHERE A__c IN :A];
```

This works because an sObject list used as a binding for B__c automatically assumes you want the Id for each A__c in the list of A__c.

Comment: wow didn't know this before, used to wonder whether it can work, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Just use a semi-join:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM B__c WHERE A__c IN (SELECT Id FROM A__c WHERE ...)
```

You can read more about this strategy in the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#!).

Comment: Thank you bro! Is semi-join inside semi-join doable?

Comment: You cannot nest semi-joins or anti-joins, no.

Comment: Noted! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Map` as a return type from SOQL. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm)

```
Map<ID, A__c> mapOfA = new Map<ID, A__c>([SELECT Id, Name FROM A__c WHERE ...]);


List<B__c> B = [SELECT Id, Name FROM B__c WHERE A__c IN :mapOfA.keySet()];
```

Comment: This is also another way to try! Thank you!